# Bootstrap datepicker remove input value if click outside the calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, calendar

I use bootstrap datepicker and initialize it with a value. Now, while the calendar is open if I click outside the calendar, then the calendar fade out and the input field becomes empty.

I created the case here

[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/7jnmmh3u/4/)

My JS:

```
$('div.date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startDate: '+1d' 
});
```

And my Html:

```
<div class="input-group date" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${today}" name="expectedDlivery">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set autoUpdateInput: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you have entered is outside of the scope based on `startDate: +1`.  Accordingly, when it is closed the datepicker code considers it an invalid entry and removes it.  Enter a value that is after today and it works.

For example, I set the date to tomorrow as follows, and it remains there when the datepicker is closed.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="13-02-2016" name="expectedDlivery">
```

Comment: Eagle eyes catch..Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just add this option to Datepicker component:

> **forceParse: false**

Example:

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    defaultDate: 'now',
    forceParse: false,
    endDate: "today"
  });
```